# Issue in numpy data type?

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np

c=np.dtype([('name','S20'), ('id','f4'), ('Marks','i1')])

d=np.array([('Ganesh',100.2,75) ], dtype = c)

print(d)
```

But the output I am getting is :

```
[(b'Ganesh', 100.2, 75)]
```

and the required output is :

```
[('Ganesh', 100.2, 75)]
```

If I am using multiple data in d then the output received is the desired one.

Comment: `b` just means it's bytes type, *which is the type you specified*. The `b` is not actually in the string. Why does it matter? It's the correct way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [114]: c=np.dtype([('name','S20'), ('id','f4'), ('Marks','i1')])                                                  
In [115]: d=np.array([('Ganesh',100.2,75) ], dtype = c)                                                              
In [116]: d                                                                                                          
Out[116]: 
array([(b'Ganesh', 100.2, 75)],
      dtype=[('name', 'S20'), ('id', '<f4'), ('Marks', 'i1')])
```

In PY3, the default string type is unicode.  `b'foo' is  bytestring.  Use 'U' instead of 'S' if you want the default:

```
In [117]: c=np.dtype([('name','U20'), ('id','f4'), ('Marks','i1')])                                                  
In [118]: d=np.array([('Ganesh',100.2,75) ], dtype = c)                                                              
In [119]: d                                                                                                          
Out[119]: 
array([('Ganesh', 100.2, 75)],
      dtype=[('name', '<U20'), ('id', '<f4'), ('Marks', 'i1')])
```